# DataBinding Text Property of UserControl to ObservableCollection does not update

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have created a UserControl, which is to display a converted string value based on the contents of a bound ObservableCollection. Everything works when the application loads; my IValueConverter is called and produces the correct string result, which is displayed correctly in my UserControl. However if the ObservableCollection contents change, my control is not updated.

Also, before I created this control, I had the same behaviour, but binding the **Content** property of a regular Button control, and this also worked correctly and updated as expected.

Any ideas what I am missing to get the same thing with my UserControl?

The control property looks like;

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));

public string Text
{
    get { return GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}
```

The relevant section in the UserControl XAML (which displays the converted string value) is;

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:MyUserControl}}, Path=Text}" />
```

And the control is created in a separate Window like so;

```
<CoreControls:MyUserControl 
    Name="myControl" 
    Text="{Binding Path=ObservableCollectionInstance, Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips guys.

I managed to work out a solution; I can handle the `CollectionChanged` event on the `ObservableCollection` and then explicitly update the target with something like;

```
BindingExpression exp = myControl.GetBindingExpression(MyUserControl.TextProperty);
if (null != exp) exp.UpdateTarget();
```

As noted, most likely, binding on the Text property is only listening to `PropertyChanged` events, not `NotifyCollectionChanged` events, but this solution does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ElementName` instead of `RelativeSource` in your binding, since you have named your user control. Also, you are trying to bind a collection to a `<Textbox>`. a `<Textbox>` is designed to display a single item. this is probably why its not working.  `ObservableCollection` fires `CollectionChanged` events, not `PropertyChanged`. Even if it did respond, you are still going to have problems because ObservableCollection does not notify when an item contained in it has property changes--only when items are added/removed etc (think, the collection itself changes).  If this is the behavior you want, you are going to have to write some code.

**EDIT**
after your comments, it sounds to me like even though you set it to OneWay binding mode, its acting like OneTime binding mode.
I would try this to help you debug it:

add this `xmlns`:

```
xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

and then, in your binding add this:

```
diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High
```

[here is an article on debugging bindings](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html).

the other thing you could do is set breakpoints in your converter. see if its actually updating when you add/remove things to your collection.  I would be willing to bet that its bc the `ObservableCollection` is NOT firing `PropertyChanged` events and that the initial update occurs because its not based on an update event.

Comment: The RelativeSource binding is on the TextBlock inside the UserControl; the UserControl is not named at that point. Regardless, that doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: I am intentionally binding to a collection so that the textbox can display 'NONE' when the collection is empty 'Item[0].SomeValue' when there is a single item in the collection and 'MULTIPLE' when more than 1 item. My IValueConverter handles this translation, and does so correctly when setting the initial DataContext on the window, but not when the ObservableCollection changes.

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableCollection` notifies only in case if items get added or removed. It is used to observe a collection. They are more suited for content controls. Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). You are talking about observing a property, which needs `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Posting more code might help, like how are you changing the value of the collection.

Comment: So is there any way to refresh the binding based on INotifyCollectionChanged ?

Comment: Also; the ObservableCollection is modified by .Clear() and .Add(...) calls.

Comment: Can you check that is the converter being called everytime you change the collection?